# Using database for Internationalization & Localization

Tags: cakephp, localization, internationalization

The CakePHP [book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1229/Internationalizing-Your-Application) has a section on Internationalization & Localization. Bascially what it says is Cake will generate a pot file and we have to create a .po for different language file from the pot file.

My problem is I want the user to be able to edit these localized text so instead of storing the localized text in the .po file I want to store them in the database.

So how can I store the localized text in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [a Behavior for that](http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1328/Translate).

Personally I find the TranslateBehavior to be rather inflexible though, so I usually just go with a separate table connected to the main model via a belongsTo relationship which contains all the translations. I then pick the one to display in the View.

Comment: That sounds strange. The Translate Bahavior is for the model data. So I have to create a model to store all the labels that I use in my views. If I do it that way then I won't be able to use something like <?php __('Posts') ?> this anymore, right?

Comment: Yes, if you want to store user editable translations in the database, you need to use a model. At that point, your labels are not simply "translatable view elements", they're data like any other data in the database. `__()` will only look up translations in .pot files, so yes, you need to use something else.